# Can I use an IEnumerable with different properties for each entry as a method argument?

Tags: c#, methods, properties, ienumerable

I'm relatively new to C#. I'm trying to use an `IEnumerable` collection as an argument to a C# function, but I want to define the properties that I want to return as well.

Suppose I have a car `IEnumerable` with properties such as `color` and `brand`. Each entry has a color and a brand, of course.
I'm trying to split the enumerable information on the function below.

Is something like this possible?

```
public string stringforeach(IEnumerable coll, <<color>>, <<brand>>)
    {
        string write = "";
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var element in coll)
        {

            write += string.Concat(i.ToString() + ";" + element.color+ ";" + element.bramd + "\n");
            i++;
        }

     

        return write;
    }
```

Comment: Firstly why are you using the non-generic `IEnumerable` and not `IEnumerable<Car>`? You say you want to "split" the information, but it looks like you are actually joining the data together. Please be clearer on what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I really would like to make it generic, so that I can iterate any element and any properties trough it. I want to be able to get pieces of information from them indeed, I'm joining together only what I want to check yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two separate features of C#:

Use [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics) so that the method can accept collections of a specific type with the compiler knowing about the specific type being used for a specific call of the method.

Use [delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/) as parameters to be able to pass functions (or [lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions)) to specify which property of an object to access.

```
public string StringForeach<T>(IEnumerable<T> coll, Func<T, string> property1, Func<T, string> property2)
{
    string write = "";
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var element in coll)
    {
        write += i + ";" + property1(element) + ";" + property2(element) + "\n";
        i++;
    }

    return write;
}
```

Given the following Car class

```
public class Car
{
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
}
```

you can call the method like this:

```
List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
cars.Add(new Car { Color = "Red", Brand = "BMW" });
cars.Add(new Car { Color = "Black", Brand = "Mercedes" });

string text = StringForeach<Car>(cars, c => c.Color, c => c.Brand);
```

---

Some explanations:

```
public string StringForeach<T>(IEnumerable<T> coll, Func<T, string> property1, Func<T, string> property2)
```

This declares a generic method which can be called with a specific type T. It accepts three parameters:

- `IEnumerable<T> coll`: A collection of objects of type T
- `Func<T, string> property1`: A delegate to a function that accepts an argument of type T and returns a string
- `Func<T, string> property2`: See above.

When calling the method

```
string text = StringForeach<Car>(cars, c => c.Color, c => c.Brand);
```

we specify that we call the method with type T being the concrete type Car.

The lambda expression

```
c => c.Color
```

is a short form of writing a function delegate for this function:

```
string SomeFunc(Car c) 
{
  return c.Color;
}
```

---

The `Bars` object from the API implements `IEnumerable`. In order to convert this into the type `IEnumerable<Bar>`, you can use this syntax:

```
IEnumerable bars = MarketData.GetBars();
IEnumerable<Bar> typedBars = bars.Cast<Bar>();
```

You can then call the method like this:

```
string text = StringForeach<Bar>(typedBars, c => c.OpenTime, c => c.Low);
```

---

Because the properties you want to use are not of type string directly, change the syntax like this:

```
public string StringForeach<T>(IEnumerable<T> coll, Func<T, object> property1, Func<T, object> property2)
{
    string write = "";
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var element in coll)
    {
        write += i + ";" + property1(element) + ";" + property2(element) + "\n";
        i++;
    }

    return write;
}
```

String conversion happens automatically.

Comment: This is excelent, thank you very much. There's only a problem, maybe not worth a new question. I have no access to the Car class since it comes from an API, and while calling the StringForeach<Cars>, visual studio returns: CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'API.Cars' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<API.Cars>'

Comment: What is the type of `API.Cars`? What types does it inherit from or what interfaces does it implement? I assume that Cars is just an example. Can you name the actual API or even link to its documentation?

Comment: yes, it's here: [link](https://ctrader.com/api/reference/internals/marketdata) under the GetBars method, it basically creates a list of time and entry prices, which in the above represented the "color" and "brand" that I meant for a car. Thanks a lot

Comment: I have extended the answer.

Comment: This is excelent, it really works.. Thanks a lot. Can I ask how do you know these things?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to specify the  type of objects in IEnumerable. [IEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=net-7.0)

For example, the class below:

```
public class itemCar
{
    public string color;
    public string brand;
    public itemCar(string _color, string _brand)
    {
        this.color = _color;
        this.brand = _brand;
    }
}
```

Then, in the `stringforeach` function, filter IEnumerable using the `<<color>>, <<brand>> properties` and create the desired output string:

```
public string stringforeach(IEnumerable<itemCar> coll, string color, string brand)
{
     string write = "";
     var carFilter= coll.Where(item => item.color == color && item.brand == brand).ToArray();

     for (int i= 0; i < carFilter.Length; i++)
         write += string.Concat(i.ToString() + ";" + carFilter[i].color + ";" + carFilter[i].brand + "\n");
    return write;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is nice, but I'd rather keep the method generic :)