# Creating a generic List with a variable number of objects

Tags: c#, list, object, generics, ienumerable

I'm trying to build a method that automatically fils a generic list.

I've put together a method like this:

```
    public List<(object, object, object)> makeList<T1>(IEnumerable<T1> coll, Func<T1, object> property1, Func<T1, object> property2, Func<T1, object> property3)
    {
        List<(object, object, object)> list = new List<(object, object, object)> { }; 
        int i = 0;

        foreach (var element in coll)
        {
            list.Add((property1(element), property2(element), property3(element)));
            i++;
        }

        return list;
    }
```

which works very well if I define the metod on start when I define 3 properties to be read:

```
            IEnumerable bars = MarketData.GetBars(TimeFrame.Hour, sn);
            IEnumerable<Bar> typedBars = bars.Cast<Bar>();
            makeList<Bar>(typedBars, c => c.OpenTime, c => c.Open, c => c.Open);
```

The problem I'm having is I don't like defining 3 objects in the list, I'd like that it somehow reads the number of properties as objects, and defines as many as I provide, and not just 3 everytime.

I'm not sure something like this is possible. Could a Tuple of objects do it?

PS: this is a follow up on: [Can I use an IEnumerable with different properties for each entry as a method argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75639946/can-i-use-an-ienumerable-with-different-properties-for-each-entry-as-a-method-ar)

Comment: a datatable doesnt work for your need?

Comment: or a nested dictionary?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this? It makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the params keyword in C# to pass parameters as much as you want. And then of course you will need to use an array instead of a tuple.

Here is an example:

```
public List<object[]> makeList<T>(IEnumerable<T> coll, params Func<T, object>[] param)
{
    List<object[]> list = new List<object[]>(); 

    foreach (var element in coll)
    {
        object[] paras = new object[param.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < paras.Length; i++)
        {
            paras[i] = param[i](element);
        }

        list.Add(paras);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: works like a charm, but instead (item) it takes (element) :) a minor detail, thanks